# "Synchronous" browsing -- make one user see what another one is doing

Tags: ajax, share, html, synchronous

I would like to implement a "guided" photo browsing. That is, when one web-site visitor chooses to be in the guided mode and another to be a guide, the former sees photos chosen by the latter.

This is similar to what Google Drive simultaneous editing looks like, when one user sees changes by another user in real time. So I was wondering if I could just use the same technology.  Does anyone know how it is implemented? Also any comments on whether it would be suitable for me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a real time socket messaging like https://www.pubnub.com/
The user that wants to see the photos will subscribe to a channel where the messages will be sent. The message gets to the user immediately.
The application will read the message in JSON format. You can include the photo name/title as well as the URL. You will process the message and load the image.

Here is an example of how they implemented a stream of Hacker News articles:

https://www.pubnub.com/developers/data-streams/hacker-news-articles